# No report is generated in Twist project

Tags: report, automated-tests, sahi, twist

I'm using Twist as IDE (Twist version - 13.1.0.13112-be932387dc00b6 - http://studios.thoughtworks.com/twist) for writing and executing automated tests using Sahi with Java.

I have created Twist project, Scenario and Executed the Scenario successfully in Twist. But after executing no HTML Report is generated in Project folder.

Is there any configuration needed to generate HTML Report?

Answer (score 1):

The question is more related to Twist rather than sahi.
By twist ide you can't get the html reports.
You have to execute your twist scenarios by ant to get the html report.
You may contact to Thoughtwork's guys for the ant's build.xml file.

Comment: You are right at that point, the question is more related to Twist rather than Sahi. I have got the solution to generate HTML report in Sahi.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on Twist Sahi project
2. Click Properties at pop up
3. Click Twist Properties at left side
4. At right side of panel: click General tab
5. Check "Generate Local Report" check box, enter a Report Location (in my case "reports")
6. Finally click OK button at bottom right corner